# `changeFilePaths` function can't change local path

Tags: matlab

I want to use mat file in another machine (mac to linux) and try to use `changeFilePaths`. According the online doc [enter link description here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/groundtruth.changefilepaths.html)

My code is as follows, gTruth.DataSource value doesn't change before and after `changeFilePath`, why?

matlab version 2022a update 3 is used.

```
>> load('groundTruthLidar.mat');
Warning: The data source for the following source names could not be loaded. C:\Source
 
> In groundTruthLidar.loadobj (line 635) 


>> gTruth.DataSource

ans = 

  PointCloudSequenceSource with properties:

            Name: "Point Cloud Sequence"
     Description: "A PointCloud sequence reader"
      SourceName: "C:\Source"
    SourceParams: [1×1 struct]
      SignalName: "Source"
      SignalType: PointCloud
       Timestamp: {[0 sec]}
      NumSignals: 1

>> currentPathDataSource = "C:\Source";
>> newPathDataSource = fullfile(matlabroot, 'toolbox', 'lidar', 'lidardata');
>> alternativeFilePaths = {[currentPathDataSource newPathDataSource]};
>> unresolvedPaths = changeFilePaths(gTruth, alternativeFilePaths)

unresolvedPaths = 

  0×0 empty string array

>> gTruth.DataSource

ans = 

  PointCloudSequenceSource with properties:

            Name: "Point Cloud Sequence"
     Description: "A PointCloud sequence reader"
      SourceName: "C:\Source"
    SourceParams: [1×1 struct]
      SignalName: "Source"
      SignalType: PointCloud
       Timestamp: {[0 sec]}
      NumSignals: 1
```

‘alternativeFilePaths’

```
>> alternativeFilePaths

alternativeFilePaths = 

  1×2 string array

    "C:\Source"    "/Applications/MATLAB_R2022a.app/too…"

>> dir(alternativeFilePaths(2))

.                                   lidarLabeler                        
..                                  lidardata_VoxelLabels.mat           
Contents.m                          pretrainedPointPillarsDetector.mat  
PandasetLidarData.pcd               sampleWPILabels.mat                 
fullParkingLotData.mat              scene_data.mat                      
hesaiFileReaderConfiguration        scene_target_reflectances.mat       
highwayScene.pcd                    segmatchMapFullParkingLot.mat       
las                                 velodyneSensorBeamAngles.mat        
lcc
```

Comment: try `alternativeFilePaths` without the `{}`, just in case.

Comment: I have tried it, the same result, path has not changed.

Comment: if you do `dir(alternativeFilePaths )`, do you get the files there? Do you have access to the folder?

Comment: `dir(newPathDataSource)` works and list matlab's installed lidar related mat files.

Comment: well, you should try with `alternativeFilePaths` because its what you are giving `changeFilePaths`

Comment: I have updated the code for 'alternativeFilePaths' and response for check.

Comment: It should not be a 2 array, it should be 1 string only. `"C:\Source/Applications/MATLAB_R2022a.app/too…"`.. Use `strcat()` or `fullfile` to make it an entire path.

Comment: "C:\Source" is windows path, it is original path. "/Applications/MATLAB_R2022a.app/too…" is my local path for replacement. I have set up the target machine with the same path to avoid the problem.

Comment: no, `/Applications/MATLAB_R2022a.app/too…` is not a full path in Windows. Look, this is not too hard: the second argument to that function has to be a full path. In Windows they start with the disk name, e.g. `D:\ ` or `C:\ `.

Comment: "C:\Source" is windows path, it is original path. "/Applications/MATLAB_R2022a.app/too…" is my local path (Mac OS) for replacement.  `alternativeFilePaths = [currentPathDataSource newPathDataSource];` the statement return a list with two elements.

Comment: Ah apologies, I see now. I am still confused on how your code can access seemly 2 operating systems though.

Comment: I have used the example in the help documents, maybe it is a bug of the current version.

Comment: Yeah, my question is: how does your code access 2 operating systems? This is not possible, as far as I know. My matlab running on windows can only access widows file paths. Even if my computer also has a linux instalation, I can't have both at the same time, this is not possible, as far as I know. So how do you want to access a mac folder? where it is?

Comment: OK, I think I understand. Have you tried what I said before : `unresolvedPaths = changeFilePaths(gTruth, newPathDataSource)` ? I.e. only giving 1 path to this function

Comment: I have tried it at the time of "comment 2", but the same result.